# How to understand this `System.ArgumentNullException` when trying to use `Concat` with `as`

Tags: c#, data-structures, casting, binary-tree

I'm trying to solve a Leetcode problem *Binary Tree Preorder Traversal*. Below is what I wrote so far :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class TreeNode
{
   public int val;
   public TreeNode left;
   public TreeNode right;
   public TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
}

public class Solution
{
   public IList<int> PreorderTraversal(TreeNode root)
   {
        if (root == null)
        {
            return new List<int> { };
        }
        else
        {
            IList<int> ret = new List<int> { root.val };
            ret = ret.Concat(PreorderTraversal(root.left)) as IList<int>;
            ret = ret.Concat(PreorderTraversal(root.right)) as IList<int>;// <-- this line
            return ret;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var root = new TreeNode(42);
        root.right = new TreeNode(99);
        var result = new Solution().PreorderTraversal(root);
    }
}
```

I tried the same algorithm with `ToList()`, it worked. But when running this code, `System.ArgumentNullException` was thrown at the line I marked. So my question is where did it come from? How to understand it? How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your initial value for `ret` is an `IList<int>`, the return type when using `.Concat` is an `IEnumerable<int>`. However you use a safe (`as`) cast back to an `IList<Int>`; that's not a valid cast and so your first `.Concat` operation returns null... The next line then tries to operate on a null value.

`.Concat` is implemented as an extension method that takes the source (`ret` in this case) as an argument so it throws an `ArgumentNullException` when null is passed.

You could fix this by using `IEnumerable<int>` as the return type and for the declaration of `ret` and removing your casts.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class TreeNode
{
   public int val;
   public TreeNode left;
   public TreeNode right;
   public TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
}

public class Solution
{
   public IEnumerable<int> PreorderTraversal(TreeNode root)
   {
        if (root == null)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<int>();
        }
        else
        {
            IEnumerable<int> ret = new List<int> { root.val };
            ret = ret.Concat(PreorderTraversal(root.left));
            ret = ret.Concat(PreorderTraversal(root.right));
            return ret;
        }
    }
}

 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var root = new TreeNode(42);
        root.right = new TreeNode(99);
        var result = new Solution().PreorderTraversal(root);
    }
}
```